# group rows based on partial strings from two columns and sum values

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['Ax','Ay','Bx','By'], 'c2':['Ay','Ax','By','Bx'], 'c3':[1,2,3,4]})

   c1  c2  c3
0  Ax  Ay   1
1  Ay  Ax   2
2  Bx  By   3
3  By  Bx   4
```

I'd like to sum the `c3` values by aggregating the same `xy` combinations from the `c1` and `c2` columns.

The expected output is

```
  c1  c2  c3
0  x   y   4   #[Ax Ay] + [Bx By]
1  y   x   6   #[Ay Ax] + [By Bx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select values in `c1` and `c2` without first letters and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby([df.c1.str[1:], df.c2.str[1:]]).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
  c1 c2  c3
0  x  y   4
1  y  x   6
```